# Clear interval not working with transitionend event in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

So as the title says I'm having problem clearing the interval when using `setInterval` with `transitionend` event, I have a piece of code where I have declared a variable called `interval` inside the `window.onload` function and I want to clear that interval when certain condition becomes true but the problem is that the interval is not getting cleared and function keeps on running. Below is my code snippet.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    let number = 0;
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    container.style.opacity = 1;
    container.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
    const colorChanger = document.querySelectorAll(".color-changer");
    const colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
    let interval;
    container.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
        colorChanger[number].style.backgroundColor = colors[number];
        number++;
        if(number === 3) {
         clearInterval(interval);
        }
       }, 500);
    });
};
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<span class="color-changer">Some</span>  
<span class="color-changer">Text</span> 
<span class="color-changer">Here</span> 
<span class="color-changer">!</span>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.container  {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 3s;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
    transform:translateX(-20%);
}
```

Comment: At each new event you start a new interval. Depending on the duration of the transition, when number is finally 3, there may be several intervals running in parallel. the variable `interval` will only point to the last of these intervals.

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry I'm a little confused but the `transitionend` event gets triggered only when the page loads and then it never occurs then how is it possible that multiple intervals would be running in parallel? and please help me find a way to run the setInterval only once so that I could clear it when the condition is met.

Comment: why would the transitionend event fire only once? Every time a CSS transition inside the container ends it will fire. You don't show your CSS not HTML, so we can't know what happens really.

Comment: @Kaiido Hello I've updated the question with code snippets of `HTML` and `CSS`,  As you could see there's a`div`  with a class `container` on it, And by default it is `translated` -20% on the X-Axis, So when the page loads in the `window.onload` function I'm `transforming`  it back to it's original position. And when the transition ends I want to trigger a `setInterval` so that I could change the color of the text in the `spans` with color-changer  `class`   I hope I have provided enough information this time. Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are transitioning two properties: `opacity` and `transform`, so the `transitionend` event fires twice,

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let number = 0;
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.style.opacity = 1;
  container.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
  container.addEventListener("transitionend", (evt) => {
    console.log("fired for", evt.propertyName);
  }, 500);
};
```

```css
.container  {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transform:translateX(-20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

two intervals run in parallel, and the `interval` variable only points to the last interval's id, so the first one can't be stopped anymore.

To avoid this, you can simply set the `once` option of `addEventListener` so that your handler is called only once:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let number = 0;
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.style.opacity = 1;
  container.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
  const colorChanger = document.querySelectorAll(".color-changer");
  const colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
  let interval;
  container.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        colorChanger[number].style.backgroundColor = colors[number];
        number++;
        if (number === 3) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 500);
    }, {
      once: true
    } // make it fire only once
  );
};
```

```css
.container {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<span class="color-changer">Some</span>
<span class="color-changer">Text</span>
<span class="color-changer">Here</span>
<span class="color-changer">!</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That was such a silly mistake, But the advantage is that now I know that we can also pass options to event listeners. :D

Answer (score 0):

can be "Uncaught TypeError" for "colorChanger[number]"
you must check that:

```js
interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(!colorChanger[number] || number > 3) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    colorChanger[number].style.backgroundColor = colors[number];
    number++;
}, 500);
```

Comment: Hi the problem is that I'm getting this `Uncaught TypeError` because `clearInterval` is not clearing the interval and it keeps calling that function again and again.

Comment: To avoid this error, you need to add an additional check. For example as shown above